# Find out Button position in array of objects

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've created a Button symbol and export it `Export for ActionScript` with class name "theButton".

There is an object and i would like to create that Button in `myObj` constructor as below :

```
public class myObj extends Sprite {
        private var myBtn:theButton = new theButton();

        public function myObj() {
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 50;
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 50;
            addChild(myBtn);
        }
        public function getXPos():uint {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create an array of `myObj` class and `getXPos()` when i do clicking on each button like so :

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();
myArray[0] = new myObj();

myArray[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);

addChild(myArray[0]);

function Clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var xPos1:uint = myObj(evt.target).getXPos();
    trace("Position is in : " + xPos1);
}
```

When clicking on the buttons appears on the screen, following error has comes up:

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert theButton@2c9dcf99 to myObj.
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evt.target` will contain a reference to the *clicked* display object, which actually is myBtn inside the myObj class (it's the only visible graphics you can click on).

There are two ways to solve this.

1. Set this.mouseChildren = false inside the myObj() constructor.
   This way a click on a child display object in myObj will be
   "counted" as a click on myObj, and evt.target will be a reference to
   an instance of myObj.
2. Instead of evt.target use evt.currentTarget. It's the instance
   you attached the event listener to, not the instance you clicked on
   (That is actually what you want in most cases).